# jquery get time from timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, date-format

I am trying to display Time on my view with format 10: 30 PM PST from time stamp with format like '2012-10-10T06:42:47Z'. I tried different ways to do that and failed. Any good option to display time in that format?

[My trail is here](https://jsfiddle.net/k0bzd3kw/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("span.localtime").localtime();
});

(function() {
  (function($) {
    return $.fn.localtime = function() {
      var fmtDate, fmtZero;
      fmtZero = function(str) {
        return ('0' + str).slice(-2);
      };
      fmtDate = function(d) {
        var hour, meridiem;
        hour = d.getHours();
        if (hour < 12) {
          meridiem = "AM";
        } else {
          meridiem = "PM";
        }
        if (hour === 0) { hour = 12; }
        if (hour > 12) { hour = hour - 12; }
        return hour + ":" + fmtZero(d.getMinutes()) + " " + meridiem + " " + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
      };
      return this.each(function() {
        var tagText;
        tagText = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(fmtDate(new Date(tagText)));
        return $(this).attr("title", tagText);
      });
    };
  })(jQuery);
}).call(this);
```

Comment: If you're able to use other libraries, check out [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It has a ton of formatting options and would make your code much simpler.

Comment: is that open source and free to use?

Comment: `var niceDate = javascriptDate.toLocaleTimeString();`  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) is more info.